# Responsive button on img-responsive bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm Trying to make text on img-responsive in bootstrap3. It's not working properly because when I make 'absolute' css it will be not responsive.
How to make button **always** apear on image and be responsive ?

Some HTML

```
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class=" col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class=" col-md-6  col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
                        <img class="left img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x250" alt="">
                        <div class="btn btn-danger button-image">
                            DOWNLOAD
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class=" col-md-6  col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">

                        <img class="left img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x250" alt="">
                        <div class="btn btn-danger button-image">
                            SEE MORE
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
          </div></div>


        <div id="push"></div>
```

Bootply
http://www.bootply.com/131025

Answer (score 0):

Change right to left :

```
.button-image{
position:absolute;
bottom:21px;
left: 130px;
width:100px;
height:30px;
}
```

You may want to think about using percentages to position it in the div though to take into account different view port sizes etc...